# Why won't my double click function open jquery dialog box?

Tags: jquery, events, dialog, bind, double-click

I have a bunch of DIVs with class dblclickable and a DIV with id="dialog-edit" but when I double click on a DIV the dialog doesn't open. How come? Um... may have something to do with the fact that I don't know how to "Bind" it...
Please help! THANKS!

```
<script>
$(".dblclickable").dblclick(function (event) {
    var tagsedit = $("#tagsedit"),
        elnameedit = $("#elnameedit"),
        mngredit = $("#mngredit");
    $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: false,
        zIndex: 101,
        buttons: {
            "Update Element": function () {
                if ($('#eltypeedit option:selected').text() == "Individual Resource") {
                    $(event.target).html(elnameedit.val() + " " + "<hr />" + mngredit.text() + tagsedit.val());
                }
                else {
                    $(event.target).html(elnameedit.val() + " " + $('#eltypeedit option:selected').text() + "<hr />" + mngredit.text() + tagsedit.val());
                }
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

@mr.nicksta the element I'm searching for most definitely HASN'T been loaded yet when the page loads. These DIVs that are being double clicked on to open the dialog bog are dynamic - they themselves were created by another dialog box... I thought by using .dblclick function the function would be called when the DIVs are double clicked?

@crazyarabian I don't want autoOpen true because I need the dialog to open more than once. Much more than once. Anytime a DIV is double clicked on.

If this function alone does not open the dialog, then therein lies my problem. I think I DO need some other function to "bind" the double click function to the dialog open function... but I don't know how to.

Comment: Have you tried using `autoOpen: true`? Otherwise, I don't see where you're actually opening the dialog.

Comment: @pleasehelpneeddesignhelp: Welcome to StackOverflow. I tidied up your code indentation with help from http://jsbeautifier.org/. :o)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried wrapping the above code in the document ready handler? it may be because your code is executing before the DOM is loaded so the element you're searching for hasn't been loaded yet. by wrapping it in document ready, it will only execute when all elements of the page have loaded e.g.

```
$(function() {
    //your code here
});
```